# How to fix incompatible types error when I want to set a pointer to NULL in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, null, variable-assignment

I ran into an incompatible type error when I try to assign a self-constructed type array to NULL.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#incldue <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
 int i;
 double j;
} MyStruct;

int main() {
 MyStruct array[10];
 ... //doing something
 *array = NULL;
 return 0;
}
```

and I compiled it on Ubuntu using:

```
 gcc -o main main.c
```

The compiler shows the following error:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'MyStruct {aka struct <anonymous>}' from type 'void *'
*array = NULL;
       ^
```

How do I assign array to NULL?

I know that an array and a pointer are different, and in most cases array names are converted to pointers. (as this question explains: [Is an array name a pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer-in-c))
But things are a little different when my program involves self-constructed structure.

I tried the following 2 things:

```
// 1st
int main() {
 int array[10];
 ... //doing something
 *array = NULL; // this gives a warning!!!
 return 0;
}
```

The code above only has a warning when I compile it, while the code below has an error.

```
// 2nd
int main() {
 MyStruck array[10];
 ... //doing something
 *array = NULL; // this gives an Error!!!
 return 0;
}
```

I also want to know what makes the difference.

Comment: You can't. You'll have to do something else. But you haven't explained what you actually want to achieve (the X in your [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: You don't; you can't assign NULL to a structure, and `*array` is equivalent to `array[0]`, which is of type `MyStruct`, which is not a pointer.

Comment: You attempt to assign NULL to the first element of array, not to the array itself. Presumably you wanted to do `array=NULL;`, but even that is not valid. What is your intention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I assign array to NULL?

You can't assign an array to `NULL`. An array is not a pointer. It is a non-modifiable l-value which can't be left operand of assignment operator.

What you are doing in the statement `*array = NULL;` is equivalent to `array[0] = NULL;`. `array[0]` is of type `MyStruct` while `NULL` is used to assign a pointer type and this makes the the operands of assignment operator incompatible.

If you are trying to set all the elements of an array to `0` then you can do as

```
MyStruct array[10] = {0};
```

Comment: Sir, it's not array, it's `*array`. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh; Read the last statement of his question and then edited part of my answer.

Comment: I agree, the variable naming is confusing here, still, OP is not trying to assign to an array, anyway. :)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I also tried:    int array[10]; *array = NULL;   This compile was successful. Why can I set int array to NULL?

Comment: @CHEN You cannot. `*array = NULL;` on int array is roughly same as `array[0] = (int)NULL;`. You just converted null pointer to integer and stored that in the first element of the array. Your compiler should give warning at least. If it didn't, check your compiler settings to make sure warnings are enabled.

Comment: @user694733 `NULL` is a null pointer constant, not necessarily a null pointer. It might (or might not be) defined as `0`.

Comment: @M.M True. But even if it compiles, it's in most cases wrong thing to do. `NULL` should be treated as null pointer, even if it were defined only as a `0`.

Answer (score 2):

`*array` produces a `MyStruct` type (non-pointer) which is not supposed to be compatible with `NULL`, a pointer type. The assignment is not valid.

That said, arrays are not assignable. They are not a valid LHS operand of assignment operator. You can assign individual elements of the array, but not the array (as in array variable name) itself.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.16

> An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

and then, chapter §6.3.2.1

> [...] A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that
>   **does not have array type**, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const-qualified
>   type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including,
>   recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const-qualified
>   type.